# How to perform Hibernate query from Hibernate perspective with annotated objects instead of hbms?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have just recently decided to redesign my database and I used annotated objects instead of hbm files. The problem is that now I am unable to build a configuration in order to check my queries. Any  ideas?

edit: By hibernate perspective I mean the Hibernate Console Perspective you can find in 3.9.1 of the following link:

http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define named queries like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "yourTable")
@NamedNativeQueries(value = {
        @NamedNativeQuery(name="nativeSelectName", 
                query = "select blah blah blah", resultClass = YourEntityClass.class)
})

@NamedQueries(value = {
        @NamedQuery(name = "hqlQuery",
            query = "from YourEntityClass where ...")
```

Comment: Hello Stanislav,
I know how to insert a query. The problem is how to run the query in the Hibernate perspective of Eclipse without the need of running the application as I was doing with hbm files